# Find two Prolog terms A and B such that: "A is B." is false. "A =:= B." is true

Tags: prolog

Could some expert in Prolog please give example of such a scenario?

```
Facts-
fruit('mango')
fruit('apple).

dif(fruit(X), fruit(Y)).

fruit(X) \= fruit(Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

```
?- 2+2 is 4.
false

?- 2+2 =:= 4.
true
```

Because:

> +Expr1 =:= +Expr2
>
> True if expression Expr1 evaluates to a number equal to Expr2.

and

> -Number is +Expr
>
> True when Number is the value to which Expr evaluates. Typically, is/2 should be used with unbound left operand.

`is` evaluates only the term on the right, =:= evaluates both.